# How to pass data in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am currently learning MVC pattern and I have a problem with understanding how to pass data from controller to model and then from model to view.

My structure looks like this

```
/controllers
    index.php
/libs
    controller.php
    main.php
    view.php
/models
    index_model.php
/views
    index.php
.htaccess
index.php
```

First I always create an main object and include files that i need

```
include 'libs/Main.php';
require 'libs/Controller.php';
require 'libs/view.php';
$main = new Main();
```

then in main class i reroute the url so correct controller is called

```
class Main {


public function __construct() {
    $url = (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null);
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    if(empty($url[0])){
        require'controllers/index.php';
        $controller = new Index();
    }else{
        $file = 'controllers/'. $url[0] .'.php';
        if(file_exists($file)){
            require $file;
        } else
        die("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the controller for index page

```
class Index extends Controller{
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); //Creates new view object from parents class
        $this->model = parent::loadModel('index');
        //there should probably exists some method that will pass the data to model
        $this->view->render('index'); //renders view, but also it should have another argument that contains data, i think
        if(isset($_POST['SubmitCosmonautForm'])){
            var_dump($_POST);
        }
    }
}
```

This is main controller that every other controller will inherit, so all have created view object

```
class Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        $this->view = new view();
    }

    protected function loadModel($name){
        $path = 'models/'.$name.'_model.php';
        if(file_exists($path)){
            require $path;
            $modelName = $name.'_model';
            $this->model = new modelName();
        }else{
            echo "Model for" .$name."doesn't exists";
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the view in library, which contains render function so far

```
class View{


    public function render($name){
        require 'views/' .$name. '.php';
    }
}
```

For example i want to save form data to database, so when i am thinking about it i should probably pass only data to model, and inside that model i should call methods that will handle saving/loading/changing DB, these methods that operates over DB could be in database class. Is this the right approach ? i read about mvc last 2 hours but i don't know if i understand it correctly.

Comment: Be careful when requiring files from user input.

Comment: Yea, I already noticed it was a bit wrong... Well, user will be able to require only files that are associated with page they are visiting.

Comment: @RyanVincent okay I saved it to array, but how should i pass it, something like '$this->model->insert("index_model.php", $data)' ? idk because I read that I should handle all business logic inside model and if I do it like this then I will do it outside or not ?  or '$this->model->load("index_model.php", $data)', this will save data to variable inside 'index_model.php' and then there i would call insert method

Comment: Do you have any good source to study MVC ? Because so far I always find different approaches to It and I am not sure which one is best... Also I should learn ORM(Object Realtional Model) so idk if it has to do anything with it.... So with your approach you have some basic models for every controller which have simple logic in them, and then you have some type of maybe parent model that implements method that uses the basic models ?